# Static std::vector cancels out if out of scope when I returned its reference

Tags: c++, vector, reference

Now I've got this peculiar bug that seemed weird. I have a class called ENGComponent that will push itself up into one of 5 private static vectors based on its priority. The vector is gotten by calling GetComponentList(priority). This is done in the constructor. But after we get out of the constructor, the pushing back is ignored and the vector got 0 item in it. Here's the code:

ENGComponent:

```
#include "../../inc/engine/eng_component.h"

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "../../inc/engine/eng_logger.h"

//Static member var inits
std::vector<ENGComponent*> ENGComponent::m_ComponentList_1 = std::vector<ENGComponent*>();
std::vector<ENGComponent*> ENGComponent::m_ComponentList_2 = std::vector<ENGComponent*>();
std::vector<ENGComponent*> ENGComponent::m_ComponentList_3 = std::vector<ENGComponent*>();
std::vector<ENGComponent*> ENGComponent::m_ComponentList_4 = std::vector<ENGComponent*>();
std::vector<ENGComponent*> ENGComponent::m_ComponentList_5 = std::vector<ENGComponent*>();

ENGComponent::ENGComponent( const std::string& name, 
                            Priority priority, 
                            ENGObject* owner): m_Name(name),
                                               m_Priority(priority),
                                               m_pOwnerObject(owner)

{
    std::vector<ENGComponent*> compList = GetComponentList(m_Priority);

    if (compList == m_ComponentList_5)
        m_Priority = PRIORITY_5;

    compList.push_back(this);

}

std::vector<ENGComponent*>& ENGComponent::GetComponentList(Priority priority)
{
    switch(priority)
    {
        case PRIORITY_1:
            return m_ComponentList_1;
        case PRIORITY_2:
            return m_ComponentList_2;
            break;
        case PRIORITY_3:
            return m_ComponentList_3;
            break;
        case PRIORITY_4:
            return m_ComponentList_4;
            break;
        case PRIORITY_5:
            return m_ComponentList_5;
            break;
        default:
            //Error! TODO: Log error, change to priority 5 and move on
            //TODO: LOG error
            std::string errMessage = "Component priority unknown! Returning priority 5...";
            ENGLogger::Log(errMessage, ENGLogger::LogLevel::ERROR);

            return m_ComponentList_5;
    }
}
```

Now, if after I instantiate the ENGComponent object, I called ENGComponent::GetComponentList(priority) anywhere else, the size of the returned m_ComponentList_X is always 0, even when I had pushed the object back. Now here comes the weird thing. If I skipped the whole priority thing, and push directly to the vector, it works just fine (ie. the vector's size incremented by one and the object is successfully pushed back). Even when I called GetComponentList() from outside the object. Like this:

```
ENGComponent::ENGComponent( const std::string& name, 
                            Priority priority, 
                            ENGObject* owner): m_Name(name),
                                               m_Priority(priority),
                                               m_pOwnerObject(owner)

{    
    m_ComponentList_5.push_back(this);
}
```

So what did I do wrong here? Can somebody please tell me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: PS the `= std::vector<ENGComponent*>()` bit is unnecessary.

Comment: `std::vector<ENGComponent*> compList = GetComponentList(m_Priority);` What is this for? You create a local copy which is destroyed when the constructor returns.

Comment: Do you mean for `compList` to be a reference to your vector, or a copy of it? Because right now it's the latter.

Comment: Instead of component1, component2 etc why not have a vector of your vectors? And priority can now be an integer for the index.

Comment: @NeilKirk Yeah, I know that it's a bit necessary. I just like to make it uniform with the default value if it were a pointer (ie. = new std::vector<ENGComponent*>()). And I didn't use vector of vectors because it became confusing in the end.

Comment: @Nemo Actually the former. You're right, it is my fault. My bad.

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<ENGComponent*>> ENGComponent::m_ComponentList(5);`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I said. Pretty complicated. Except if you use typedef. And also, it would somewhat affect performance to look for the list in the vector because this object can be in the thousands or tens of thousands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `GetComponentList` is returning reference of the vector, you are storing it into `compList` as a separate copy. Hence any element addition into `compList` does not get added to the original vector.

You need to store the vector into a reference:

```
std::vector<ENGComponent*>& compList = GetComponentList(m_Priority);
```

So any modifications to `compList` would reflect to the original vector.

There is nothing weird about:

```
m_ComponentList_5.push_back(this);
```

Here you are making modification directly using the vector. Hence this works fine.

Comment: IC. Thanks for the answer. I suck at references, I confess. And worse, I am currently working with either C# / Objective C / JavaScript nowadays. And their concept of pointer and reference kind of screwed my C++. :P

Answer (score 0):

You shuold use reference:

```
std::vector<ENGComponent*>& compList = GetComponentList(m_Priority);
```